# Can't start Apache on Centos 7

Tags: apache, vps, centos7

I installed apache with

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Than I try to start apache with

```
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I run

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

And I get the following message:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 51 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache/mod_mpm_prefork.so into server: /usr/lib/apache/mod_mpm_prefork.so: undefined symbol: ap_set_listencbratio
```

And I also run

```
journalctl -xe
```

And I get:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 51 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.co
```

How can I solve this ? it's so frustrating

Comment: What is on `line 4 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf`?

Comment: LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_mpm_prefork.so

Comment: Hey I solved it with: cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build apache
./build php n
./build rewrite_confs

Comment: When I encountered this error, it was because I had a mix of modules from /usr/lib64/httpd (stock httpd package) and /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd (httpd24 package).